# I try adding a ROW to a VIEW, but it does not appear in it, yet it does in the TABLEthe view was created from

Tags: sql, database

Provided a table of employees table1, I had to create a view listing employee who had a managerial position. No problem. 
Then from this view had to list those who belonged to department 10. No problem.
 But then, still in the same view,  I'm asked to insert a new salesman belonging to department 20. 
When doing this, the newly created row doesn't appear in the view, but does appear in the original table1. I do not understand why. Here is my code :

```sql
-- I create the view here

create view v_senior 
as
select *
from emp
where job like 'manager' or job like 'president';

--Here I filter by department 10

select *
from v_senior
where deptno = 10;


-- Here I try to add the new Salesman

insert into v_senior (empno, ename, job, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm, deptno)
values(8888,'Luxian', 'SALESMAN', '5678', '2019-06-06', '100000', '500', 20)
```

And this is where when I try to fetch all data from v_senior, only data returned is the employee in a managerial position, no sign of my newly added salesman. But this salesman does appear when I fetch all data from emp (the original table). Would any one have an explanation for me please, I am feeling lost with no idea of what went wrong.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Your view has a WHERE condition to limit data based on 'manager' or 'president', but you are inserting a 'salesman' job, so it will not be part of the view.  It's working as expected.  Why do you think it should be otherwise?

Comment: If your query is only looking for job of 'manager' or 'president', why do you expect to see a row without that value?

Comment: I thought that WHERE statement would only be retroactive, but it does impact any newly added row ? I added it directly to the view, not to the table, yet it appears in the table. Thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Thank you for your answer, but I'm just following the steps on my homework sheet. here are the steps listed 1.2 Using the view created in 1.1 to:

1.2.1 List all the senior employees who are in department 10.

1.2.2 Insert a new salesman into department 20.

1.2.3 List all senior employees.

Comment: "I thought that WHERE statement would only be retroactive" -- No. A view is more or less a stored query that is reexecuted every time the view is queried. "but it does impact any newly added row ?" Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Your view is filtering out the new data because of the filter condition in the view.

As this is a homework problem, I am assuming the instructor is possibly asking you to insert the mismatched row in the EMP table directly and observe that it is not visible in the view (that's what views are for). But you found a more interesting case by inserting in the view instead, this "disappearing row" behavior is a well-known phenomenon.

You can prevent the "disappearing row" behavior easily:

```
create view v_senior
as
select *
from emp
where job like 'manager' or job like 'president'
with check option;
```

The **with check option** bit tells Oracle to verify that any changes you make using the view (INSERTS or UPDATES) are still visible when the view is queried.
This feature exists to allow you to prevent situations like you encountered.

It is an optional feature, and if you do not enable it, you will see the "disappearing row" problem from time to time.

With the new view I did a (slightly modified) insert:

```
insert into v_senior (empno, ename, job, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm, deptno)
values(8888,'Luxian', 'SALESMAN', '5678', DATE'2019-06-06', '1000', '500', 20)
```

And got this error:

> ORA-01402: view WITH CHECK OPTION where-clause violation

And that is expected.